# Semantic token in VScode extension is not appearing in developer inspection

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I am working on development LSP server for PDF. I implemented semantic token. When I check PDF through developer inspection of VScode, I only see the textmate scopes not SemTokens. I checked that the semantic tokens are correctly coming to the client from server by consoling out.
For past couple of days, I tried all possible ways to resolve this, but still got stuck.
Anyone with experience in Typescript based VScode extension development alongside with semantic token please help.

Thank you.

[current vscode developer inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de5Mb.png)
The image should have semtokens that I added too.